# Rails application not pre-compliling asset into public\assets

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a Rails 4.0 app with following directory structure

```
-app
|->javascript
  |->page-specific
    |->myjavasript.js
```

In my application.css I have removed required tree directive to make sure I don't include all js on every page.

> //= require_tree .

Now to include my javasript I used following syntax on my page:

> 

The application works fine on my development environment but when I push my changes to my production environment, I get 404 when I browser make a call to get javascript.

I call made in production is:

> server-name/javascripts/page_specific/myjavasript.js

I call made in develop machine is:

> server-name/assets/page_specific/myjavasript.js?body=1

I read a bit about asset pipelines and added following to my production.rb:

> config.assets.precompile += ['page_specific/myjavasript.js']

But still my public\assets folder doesn't contain myjavasript.js, and keep on getting a 404.

I have a couple of questions, I do I add page specific (not-cpntroller specific) assets to my app?

Why is it working on development and not in production, what is done differently?

How can I fix it?

In firebug I see:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://my-server/javascripts/page_specific/myjavasript.js"
```

Comment: you skipped adding error logs.

Answer (score 0):

Just try,

```
config.assets.precompile += ["page-specific/*"]
```

Then, open up rails console and run the below line to know whether `page-specific` folder is there under your app asset paths:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths
```

Hope it helps :)